# Why my custom protocol is not being call? Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 VC, one where the users write the data, with textfield or pickerview, and the main screen where i show the data on a tableview. The problem is that when i click on done button, it might call the delegate, but on the first vc, where is implemented, it doesnt receive any call. What should i do? I have been for 2 days trying to find the bug, and nothings happens. Thanks for any Help.

2VC.h

```
@protocol AddCountryDelegate <NSObject>

@required

-(void)didCreateCountry:(CountryClass*)country;

@end

@interface AddCountryViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign, nonatomic) id<AddCountryDelegate> customDelegate;
```

2VC.m

```
- (IBAction)actionDone:(id)sender {

    NSString* itemName = self.itemNameTextField.text;
    NSString* countryName = self.countryNameTextField.text;
    NSDate *countryDate = [datePickerView date];
    NSString *daysLeftString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ days", self.daysLeftTextField.text];

    NSInteger daysLeftInt = [daysLeftString integerValue];

    NSNumber *daysLeft = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:daysLeftInt];

    NSString *paymentMethod = self.paymentMethodTextField.text;

    CountryClass* newCountryItem =
    [[CountryClass alloc] initWithCountryName:countryName countryLogo:@"" itemName:itemName countryDate:countryDate daysLeft:daysLeft andPaymentMethod:paymentMethod];

    [self.customDelegate didCreateCountry:newCountryItem];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

And finally the implementation on the 1st VC:

```
-(void)didCreateCountry:(CountryClass *)country{

    //Add new country-itemCountry - UPDATING OUR MODEL DATA

    NSMutableArray *mutableCountries = [self.countries mutableCopy];

    [mutableCountries addObject:country];

    self.countries = [mutableCountries copy];

    //UPDATING THE VIEW

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"Created");

    [self saveCountriesToDisc];

}

-(void)saveCountriesToDisc{

    NSMutableArray* convertedCountries = [NSMutableArray array];

    //Converting the model to dictionary

    for(CountryClass *country in self.countries)
    {
        NSDictionary *convertedCountry = [shop countriesToDictionary];
        [convertedCountries addObject:convertedCountry];
    }

    //NOW convertedShows CONTAINS ONLY STRINGS, NUMBERS,
    //ARRAYS AND DICTIONARY
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths.firstObject;

    NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"countriesListData.plist"];

    //NOW TELL THE ARRAY TO SAVE
    [convertedCountries writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"Saved");

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I initialize my delegate on the prepareforsegue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                sender:(id)sender
{


      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddSegue"]) {

            AddCountryViewController* addCountryVC =
            segue.destinationViewController;
            addCountryVC.customDelegate = self;

    }
```

Comment: where do you initialize delegate? I guess your delegate is nil

Comment: I think i initialize on the Segue: Edited the main question. Isnt this the way to do?

Comment: Is this part being called?

Comment: The prepareforsegue? Yes, it goes perfectly to the 2nd one, and also to the firstone, but the delegate implementation is not being called

Answer (score 0):

where in VC1 did you set the customDelegate to `self`?

also you should set your delegate to `weak` not `assign`

Comment: I think i initialize on the Segue: Edited the main question. Isnt this the way to do? About the weak-assign i read on internet that is almost the same, and i have tried with both, but nothing happens

Comment: I changed to weak to try, but still not working. Do i need to initialize the delegate on the 1st viewdidload or anithing similar?

Comment: no, what you did should work, 1st VC.h you have <AddCountryDelegate>?

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController <AddCountryDelegate> I dont understand where is the mistake :(